# Any useful tip on how can I make this navigation links show on wider screen(desktop etc)?

Tags: html, css

When I try to go from mobile to desktop screen , navigation does not show up.I am pretty much a beginner in frontend, so any hint on this is welcome.
I did responsive part for header links to show from 50em screeen width, but i could not show it appropriately.Still not sure(do not know) how to get this to work.

Here's my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Sunnyside agency landing page_challenge_1</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Barlow:wght@600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fraunces:wght@700;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <!--HEADER-->
    <header>
        <nav>
            <a href="#">
                <img src="./images/logo.svg" alt="Sunnyside logo" class="logo">
            </a>

            <a href="#" class="header__menu">
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
            </a>

            <div class="header__links">
                <a href="#" class="header__text" class="header__link">About</a>
                <a href="#" class="header__text" class="header__link">Services</a>
                <a href="#" class="header__text" class="header__link">Projects</a>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-contact" class="header__link">Contact</a>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <!--HERO-->
    <section class="home__hero">
        <div class="container">
            <h1 class="title">We are Creatives</h1>
            <img src="./images/icon-arrow-down.svg" alt="down arrow" class="hero__arrow">
        </div>
    </section>
    <!--ABOUT-->
    <section class="about__cta">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="about__card bg__spec__img__1">
            </div>
            <div class="about__card">
                <h4 class="transform__title">Transform your brand</h4>
                <p class="transform__par">We are a full-service creative agency specializing
                    in helping brands grow fast.Engage your clients
                    through compelling visuals that do most of the marketing
                    for you.
                </p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn__cta">Learn More</a>
            </div>
            <div class="about__card bg__spec__img__2">
                <img src="./images/mobile/image-stand-out.jpg" alt="Call to action image">
            </div>
            <div class="about__card">
                <h4 class="standout__title">Stand out to the right audience</h4>
                <p class="standout__par">Using a collaborative formula of designers, researchers,
                    photographers, videographers, and copywriters, we'll
                    build and extend your brain in digital places.
                </p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-cta"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="about__card graphic__design__card">
                <h4>Graphic Design</h4>
                <p>Great design makes you memorable.We deliver artwork
                    that underscores your brand message and captures
                    potential client's attention.
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="about__card photo__card">
                <h4>Photography</h4>
                <p>Increase your credibility by getting the most stunning,
                    high-quality photos that improve your business image.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>



    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is my CSS(not finished, in progress):

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* font-family: 'Fraunces', serif;
   font-family: 'Barlow', sans-serif; */


/* global styles
   ---------------- */
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

/* typography 
------------- */
.transform__title, 
.standout__title {
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-family: 'Fraunces', serif;
    margin: 2.5em 1em 1.5em 1em;
    text-align: center;
    width: 55vw;
}

.transform__par,
.standout__par {
    font-family: 'Barlow', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: 1.6;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 1.5em;
    margin: 0em 1em 1em 1em;
    width: 60vw;
    font-size: 1.125em;
    color: hsl(232, 10%, 55%);
}




/* buttons
   --------- */
.btn {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 0.6em 1.75em;
    border-radius: 50px;
    font-family: 'Fraunces', serif;
    font-weight: 900;
    color: hsl(212, 27%, 19%);
}

.btn__cta {
    padding-bottom: 2em;
    background: transparent;
}

@media (min-width: 50em) {
    .btn {
        font-size: 0.925em
    }

    .header__text {
        font-size: 0.925em;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 60em) {
    .btn {
        font-size: 1em;
    }
}

/* header
   --------- */
header {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

nav {
    height: 7vh;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 2.5em 1.5em;

    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

.header__menu {
    position: absolute;
    right: 5%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(5%, -50%);
}

span {
    display: block;
    width: 25px;
    height: 2px;
    background: white;
    margin: 5px;
    transition: all 400ms ease-in-out;
}

.header__links {
    font-size: 1.125em;
    font-family: 'Barlow', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 200;

    z-index: 98;

}

.header__text {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 200;

    z-index: 99;
}

.header__text:hover {
    color: #eee;
}

.header__text:not(:last-child) {
    margin-right: 1.125em;
}

/* header===responsive
-------------------- */
@media screen and (min-width: 23.4375em) {
    body {
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }

    .header__links {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 110%;
        right: 50%;
        transform: translateX(160%);
        transition: transform 400ms ease-in-out;
        background: white;
        width: 90vw;
        height: 40vh;

        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
        align-items: center;
    }

    .header__links::after {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top: -1em;
        right: 0em;

        border-width: 1em;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: transparent white transparent transparent;
    }

    .header__text {
        color: hsl(213, 9%, 39%);
    }

    .header__text:hover {
        color: hsl(210, 4%, 67%);
    }

    .btn {
        background: hsl(51, 100%, 49%);
    }
}

/* mobileMenu 
------------- */
.burgerActive {
    transform: translateX(50%);
}

.header__menu.anim span:nth-child(1) {
    transform: translate(5px, 8px) rotate(135deg);
}

.header__menu.anim span:nth-child(2) {
   opacity: 0;
}
.header__menu.anim span:nth-child(3) {
    transform: translate(5px, -8px) rotate(-135deg);
}
/* ----------------------------- */

@media screen and (min-width: 50em) {
    .header__links {  
        display: block; 
    }

    .header__menu {
        display: none;
    }
}



/* home-hero 
------------ */
.home__hero {
    background-image: url('./images/mobile/image-header.jpg');
    padding: 10em 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: bottom 20% right;
    font-family: 'Fraunces', serif;
}

.title {
    color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-size: 3rem;
    padding-bottom: 3.5em;
}

.container {
    position: relative;
}

.hero__arrow {
    position: absolute;
    right: 50%;
    top: 60%;
    transform: translateX(50%);
}


/* about 
------------ */
.about__cta {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto;

}

.about__card {
    width: 100%;
    border: 2px solid red;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.bg__spec__img__1 {
    background-image: url('./images/mobile/image-transform.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;

    min-height: 45vh;
}
```

Comment: FYI it's generally frowned upon to post so much code when most of it isn't relevant to the crux of the problem. In the future, you should try to make the simplest representation of your problem as you can, without all the detail specific to your actual project. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

This can sometimes help you to answer your own question as well.

Comment: Could you create a codepen and add your codes there ?

Comment: Kaung Khant Zaw -yes, sure.Link to codepen project is here:
https://codepen.io/zdrax93/pen/LYyRMWM
don't mind images missing, because they are stored on my local computer.Anyway, it is enough to see only that specific header items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<nav>` element in the header has a height of `0`, according to chrome inspector.

Culprit appears to be some combination of the following styles on `.header__links` being applied in this media query: `@media screen and (min-width: 23.4375em)`:

```css
position: absolute;
transform: translateX(160%);
height: 40vh;
```

If I remove the above styles then I can see the desktop header, so my guess is you'll need to add an additional media query (with a larger, more desktop-appropriate `min-width` value) that overrides those styles with something more like what you're going for for your desktop UI. You'll likely need to play around with it to get it to look right.

Comment: Thank you man.This one helped a lot.I have used properties that you listed above to modify them in my new media query of min-width: 50em.So from 50em to larger screen sizes i have set something like:  
 @media screen and (min-width: 50em) {
      .header__links {
           position: relative;
        transform: translateX(55%);
        background: transparent;
        height: 7vh;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: flex-end;
      }
    
    .header__links::after {
       display: none;
     }
  }
Works just fine.Thanks again!